# How to initialise a many-to-many class with SQLAlchemy using classical mapping

Tags: sqlalchemy, many-to-many

I'm using SQLAlchemy and have a many-to-many relationship between Parents and Children:

tables.py

```
parentLinkTable = Table('parent_links', metadata,
    Column('parent_id', BigInteger, ForeignKey('parent.id'), primary_key=True),
    Column('child_id', BigInteger, ForeignKey('child.id'), primary_key=True)
)

parentTable = Table('parent', metadata,
    Column('id', BigInteger, primary_key=True),
    Column('notes', Text)
)

childTable = Table('child', metadata,
    Column('id', BigInteger, primary_key=True),
    Column('notes', Text)
)
```

entities.py

```
class Parent():

    children = sqlalchemy.orm.relationship('Child', secondary=tables.parentLinkTable, back_populates='parents')


    def __init__(self, children: list, **kwargs):

        self.children = children

        for key, value in kwargs.items():
            setattr(self, key, value)

class Child():

    parents = sqlalchemy.orm.relationship('Parent', secondary=tables.parentLinkTable, back_populates='children')

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):

        for key, value in kwargs.items():
            setattr(self, key, value)
```

orm.py

```
import tables
import entities

sqlalchemy.orm.mapper(entities.Child, tables.childTable)
sqlalchemy.orm.mapper(entities.Parent, tables.parentTable)
```

application.py

```
children = session.query(Child).all()
parent = Cluster(children)
session.add(parent)
session.commit()
```

This code runs with no errors. However, while a new Cluster is persisted, no entries are created on the *clusterLinkTable*. I think the problem lies with the mixture of classical and declarative mapping. I think I am meant to use *properties* in sqlalchemy.orm.mapper but I am not sure how.

Comment: The first and second examples should work. When something doesn't work, please include the full stack trace and error message.

Comment: @univerio There are no errors. When I call session.commit() the Parent is flushed correctly, however the Children are not.

Comment: Are you sure that you've defined `__init__` correctly? As it stands your example is not valid syntax.

Comment: @univerio Ah, sorry. Good spot. However, the typo was in my example code (now corrected), not in my actual code. `__init__` does fire as I have stepped though it with the debugger. Parent.children is correctly assigned to become a list using the first example "self.children = children". When the session is persisted Parent gets flushed but no entries appear in the association table.

Comment: `self.children = children` works fine, so you must have something else going on. Please post a minimal example that reproduces the issue.

Comment: @univerio Ok. Code added that replicates the problem. Initially I had simplified the problem because I thought the problem was just me not knowing how to assign the children. As you say this is not where the error lies I have included the full code. Apologies for the reticence.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not using classical mapping correctly. Please refer to the [documentation](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/mapping_styles.html#classical-mappings) for a complete example. In particular, you cannot declare any relationships or columns inside the class itself. The correct incantation is:

```
class Parent(object):
    def __init__(self, children: list, **kwargs):
        ...

class Child(object):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        ...

sqlalchemy.orm.mapper(entities.Child, tables.childTable, properties={
    "parent": sqlalchemy.orm.relationship(entities.Parent, secondary=tables.parentLinkTable, back_populates='children')
})
sqlalchemy.orm.mapper(entities.Parent, tables.parentTable, properties={
    "children": sqlalchemy.orm.relationship(entities.Child, secondary=tables.parentLinkTable, back_populates='parents')
})
```

Comment: This solves the problem. Many thanks. Read the docs many times over, but must have missed that.